# How to use mods and HD textures at the same time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm using first [MCPatcher-2.0.0-beta3](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=1021&t=252531) to make HD texture packs work (and it complains if I apply mods first), but as soon as I use [TFC's Mod Manager 1.3 beta](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=141904) to install a mod ([Risugami's ModLoader](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?t=80246)), the game doesn't get farther than the checking update screen. I'm running Windows 7, 64-bit.

Any chances to make this work?

Comment: I don't really know much about mod managers, I've always installed my mods manually. Have you tried installing ModLoader directly?

Comment: @Thrillho no, but it turned out TFC's Mod Manager (or the ModLoader?) implicitly already applies the HD patch, so MCPatcher isn't necessary at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was playing around with this yesterday, actually, because I was having problems.

I manually installed ModLoader by adding the files to minecraft.jar, THEN I ran MCPatcher (I was using 1.2 though) to use an HD texture.  (I also applied the GLSL shaders which I had to do last).  It should work if you do this!

Comment: thanks. After your comment I tried this, and - behold - I didn't have to run MCPatcher at all. Apparently TFC's newest Mod Manager or the ModLoader includes the HD texture patch already...

Comment: Oh really?  I'll have to try that.